# upper limit of $\cos (x^2)-\cos (x+1)^2$ is $2$

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that upper limit of $\cos (x^2)-\cos (x+1)^2$ is $2$.

Can anyone show proof of this?

Comment: What's *upper limit*? $\sup_x(\cos x^2-\cos(x+1)^2)$ or $\limsup_{x\to\infty}$?

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker. However according to Wikipedia, upper lmit means limit superior.

Comment: @FrankScience not to be confused with "upper bound"

Comment: Do you have the same homework as the OP for [Find upper and lower limit of $\cos⁡(x^2)−\cos⁡((x+1)^2)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527767/find-upper-and-lower-limit-of-cosx2-cosx12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the sum to product formula:

$$ \cos a + \cos b = \sin \tfrac{a+b}{2}\cos \tfrac{a-b}{2} $$

Hmm is that right?  I never remember the correct combinations of + and -  symbols. Let's see:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{2\pi i \, \frac{a+b}{2}} - e^{-2\pi i \, \frac{a+b}{2}}\right) \times \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{2\pi i \, \frac{a-b}{2}} + e^{-2\pi i \, \frac{a-b}{2}}\right)$$

If I am lucky we re-group the terms and it comes out correct:

$$ \frac{1}{4} \left( e^{2\pi i \, a} + e^{-2\pi i \, a}\right) + 
   \frac{1}{4} \left( e^{2\pi i \, b} - e^{-2\pi i \, b}\right) 
$$

This is wrong... I have written $\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos a - \sin b \right)$, but you can imagine with the correct choice of signs we can get it to work.

A quick look at [SOS math](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html) gives:

$$ \boxed{ \cos a + \cos b = 2 \,\cos \frac{a+b}{2} \, \cos \frac{a-b}{2} } $$

even pros get it wrong :-)

---

Let's try to solve your problem now... Let $a = (x+1)^2$ and $b = x^2$.  Then:

$$ \cos (x+1)^2 - \cos x^2 = 2 \,\sin \left(x^2 + x + \frac{1}{2} \right) \, \sin \left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right) \leq 2$$

We know that $\boxed{\cos x \leq 1}$ always.  So our number is always less than $2$.  In fact, the [$\limsup$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493526/can-some-clearly-explain-about-lim-sup-and-lim-inf) is $2$.  This boils down to solving for integers:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x + \frac{1}{2}&\approx& \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n_1 \hspace{0.5in}\text{ with }n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}\\
x^2 + x + \frac{1}{2}&\approx& \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n_2 \hspace{0.5in}\text{ with }n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{eqnarray*}

It may be surprising at first, how these questions about trigonometry turn into questions of [diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem).  This system of equation is easy to solve let's substitute one equation into the other

$$ x^2 + \left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)\approx 
x^2 + \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n_1 \right)\approx
\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n_2  $$

This leads to $x \approx \sqrt{2\pi (n_2 - n_1)}= \sqrt{2\pi n_3}$ and yet $x \approx \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right) + 2\pi n_1$ where we are looking mod $2\pi$.

**Remark I** If I choose units correctly we can look mod $1$ and just igonore all the numbers before the decimal point looking only at the "cents"  $\pi = \color{red}{3}.14159 \mod 1 \equiv \color{green}{0}.14159$

**Remark II** Proving that $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ is [equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Equidistribution_modulo_1) mod $1$ is clear since the numbers are getting closer and closer together

$$ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{ n} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}} \approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} $$

Using a computer we can plot this function and see that we have a chance at getting the numbers to be close:

[image]

Further analysis of the numbers appearing after the decimal point in $\sqrt{n}$ is extremely difficult.  Here, two Harvard professors duking it out over the gap distribution [[1](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/sqrts/sqrts.pdf)].

Comment: The modern theory is this type of simultaneous approximation, $\sqrt{m} \approx n + \sqrt{2}$ is related to dynamical systems like planets orbiting around the Sun.  If you want, see Etienne Ghys on *pétits diviseurs* or [small divisors](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/resonancesmall.pdf).  This is not important right now.

Comment: Really nice remarks and solution! +1

Answer (score 7):

This problem appeared in the recent past, and I answered it, but I can't find it now. It goes like this: Let $x_n = \sqrt {2\pi n}.$ Then

$$\cos x_n^2 - \cos (x_n+1)^2 =  1 - \cos (2\sqrt {2\pi n} + 1).$$

Now $\cos (2\sqrt {2\pi n} + 1)$ is dense in $[-1,1].$* It follows that the desired upper limit is $2.$

*Suppose $a_1 < a_ 2 <\cdots \to \infty$ and $a_{n+1}-a_n \to 0.$ Then $e^{ia_n}$ is dense in the unit circle. Proof: This is because this sequence of points orbits the unit circle infinitely many times (because $a_n \to \infty$), in steps of arc length $a_{n+1}-a_n \to 0.$ It follows that for any fixed arc $A$ of positive length,  $e^{ia_n}$ lands in $A$ infinitely many times: You can't step over $A$ if your steps have arc length less than the length of $A.$ This gives the desired density.

Now check that $a_n = 2\sqrt {2\pi n} + 1$ satisfies the above. This implies $\cos a_n$ is dense in $[-1,1].$

---

I found my previous answer to this question: [How to compute $\limsup$ and $\liminf ,\;$ as $x\to+\infty,\;$ of $\;\sin(x^2+x+1/2)\sin(x+1/2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506325/how-to-compute-limsup-and-liminf-as-x-to-infty-of-sinx2x/1506812#1506812)

Comment: Where I can find that this set is dense in $[-1,1]$?

Comment: I proved it in the previous answer. I'm trying to find it.

Comment: Dear zhw! I can only prove that $\{m+\sqrt{\alpha}n: m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But i can't prove the same result for $\cos$

Comment: @RaheemNajib Note that $f(\overline A)\subseteq\overline{f(A)}$ when $f$ is continuous.

Comment: So what? I know that inclusion formula

Comment: @FrankScience, Taking $f=\cos$ which is continuous and $A=\{m+\sqrt{\alpha}n:m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ we get $[-1,1]\subset \overline{\cos\{m+\sqrt{\alpha}n:m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}}\subset [-1,1]$. Am I right?

Comment: @RaheemNajib Yes.

Comment: @FrankScience, I know that inclusion but I don't know that it's so useful! Thank you! :) Great application!

Comment: I added some details on the density claim. (Could not find my previous post!)

Comment: @zhw. Dear friend! You proof seems nice but I am not so smart to understand it. What you think about proof which uses above inclusion?

Comment: Take a little more time to try and understand it; it's actually simple and intuitive.

Comment: By the way you wrote $x_n=2\sqrt{2\pi n}+1$ and $x_n=\sqrt{2\pi n}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @FrankScience, but $\{2\sqrt{2\pi n}+1: n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Right? because the second term is fixed.

Comment: @RaheemNajib but what about $\{2\sqrt{2n\pi}+2m\pi+1\}$?

Comment: This set has not form $\{m+n\sqrt{\alpha}\}$. Right?

Comment: @zhw. You are right, and I realize that we have exposed too much. In fact, most of these steps should be left as exercises (such as the choice of $x_n$, and the density) with hints.

Comment: @RaheemNajib It's not related to whether you are smart. It's very harmful for us to give you too many details, which will stop you from thinking problems and destroy your ability to prove new things.

Comment: but your hint about $\{2\sqrt{2n\pi}+2m\pi+1\}$ is false.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @zhw. Sorry for stupid question. Am I right that $\{2\sqrt{2n\pi}+2\pi m+1\}$ is not dense in reals?

Comment: @zhw. We know that $\{m+\sqrt{\alpha}n:m,n\}$ is dense. But above set has not the same form.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The density result I gave is more elementary than this other stuff you're talking about

Comment: @zhw, Why from densite $e^{ia_n}$ we get density of $\cos$?

Comment: Isn't it clear that if those points are dense on the circle, then the $x$ coordinates of those points are dense in $[-1,1]?$

Answer (score 2):

Well, $\cos (\text{anything})$ is always between $1$ and $-1$.  So the largest value you could *potentially* get from an expression of the form
$$\cos(\text{something}) - \cos(\text{something else})$$
would be attained by making the first cosine $1$ and the second cosine $-1$, in which case the result would be $1 - (-1) = 2$.  So in any case, $2$ is an *upper bound* for the result.

So now the question is, can we actually attain that bound?  To do so we would need to have $x^2$ be an even multiple of $\pi$ (because those are the values that yield $\cos(x^2)=1$, and we would need $(x+1)^2$ be an odd multiple of $\pi$ (because those are the values that yield $\cos(x+1)^2 = -1$).

Unfortunately those two conditions cannot be simultaneously met.  If $x^2 = 2n \pi$ for some integer $n$, then $x = \sqrt{2n\pi}$, in which case $(x+1)^2 = (1 + \sqrt{2n\pi})^2=1 + 2n\pi + 2\sqrt{2n\pi}$, which is not an odd multiple of $\pi$.

This assumes that you are expressing your angles in radians.  If you are measuring angles in degrees, you need $x^2$ to be an even multiple of $180$, and $(x+1)^2$ to be an odd multiple of $180$.  I will leave it to you check whether that is possible, and if so, what the solution is.

Comment: Nice comment! I understand almost all moments. So what we get?

Comment: @RFZ that is a different question, and requires completely different methods to solve.  I would suggest posting it as a new question.

Comment: I thought that his initial problem was to find the upper limit of $\cos(x^2)-\cos(x+1)^2$

Comment: It was not clear whether the question was to show that $2$ is *an* upper bound, or *the* maximum value.  If the question was to show that $2$ is *the maximum value*, then the question is asking you to prove something false, which I cannot help you with.

Comment: I need to show that $2$ is an upper limit of above function